# Updating to next head of a LIST ADT, without using iterator

Tags: java, list, adt

How would I go about updating to a new head node without using next?

```
private E head;
private someList<E> tail;

public E removeHead(){
        this.tail = this.tail.getTail();  
        return this.head;
    }
```

Comment: Anyone :D? Or even a point to documentation would be amazing.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want?

```
public E removeHead(){
    E oldhead = this.getHead();  // keep old head, so we can return it
    this.head = this.getTail().getHead(); // new head: comes out of old tail
    this.tail = this.getTail().getTail(); // new tail: remainder of old tail
    return oldhead;
}

public getHead(){ return head;}

public getTail(){ return tail;}
```

I presume you have implemented `getTail` already??

Comment: not quite - you want `oldhead=this.getHead()`, and then `this.head=this.getTail().getHead()`, and then `this.tail=this.getTail().getTail()`.  answer edited.

Comment: um, you havent shown us the code for your constructor. If it's `someList(head,tail)`, then in principle you can add an item at the head-end with `{return new someList<E>(e,this)}`. I.e., the `this` becomes the new `tail`.